# Please help identifying this herb

Tags: herbs, food-identification

[image]

I can’t figure out what herb this is. It tastes kind of bitter!

Comment: It looks like beet to me.

Comment: maybe dandelion ?

Comment: Beet greens would have mode red veins. Dandelion leaves have a more 3d shape. My guess is Epazote (common in Mexican cuisine). It would be easier to identify if you photographed one of the leaves spread out on a flat surface and maybe with a size reference (like a ruler).

Comment: Can you add some more information -- where did you find it, especially :)

Comment: not dandelion, the edges are smoother

Comment: Thank you everybody I think epazote might be it, it came home with me accidentally from a Mexican/Asian Supermarket!

Answer (score 4):

Where did you get it?  Looks like it could be epazote.

[image]

Comment: I've only seen it dried, but it is bitter and the leaf shape matches

Comment: definitely epazote.